# Firebase React Native Real time database initial load and updates

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to load the initial chats at chats/chatID/messages/ with this code:

```
    /**
     * load initial messages
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        chatRef.child('messages').orderByChild('createdAt').once('value').then(snapshot => {
            setMessages(Object.values(snapshot.val() || {}))
        })
    }, [])

    /**
     * update on new message
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        const onValueChange = chatRef.child('messages')
            .on('child_added', snapshot => {
                const data = snapshot.val()
                console.log(currentUser.uid, 'New message', data)
                if (data) {
                    setMessages(previousMessages =>
                        GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, snapshot.val()),
                    )
                }
            });

        return () => chatRef.off('child_added', onValueChange);
    }, [])
```

But I am getting this:

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `2bdc64eb-3514-4015-ae6a-c900df1f8334`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Because the onValueChange function is called but even when no data is added to the reference. It is just loaded once...

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: `onValueChange` <> `on('child_added'`

From the Firebase documentation:

> `child_added` - Retrieve lists of items or listen for additions to a list of items. **This event is triggered once for each existing child** and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The listener is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data.

So when you call `on('child_added'` you're going to get called for each existing child right away, which means that you get the same children there as you get in the `.once('value')` handler, and React then correctly complains about getting the same keys twice.

You likely only need the `onValueChange`, and not the `.once('value')`.

---

If you want to call `setMessages` only once for the initial set of messages. In that case you can combine `on('value'` and `on('child_added'`, using the latter to handle the data - and the former to detect when it is completed.

When you have both listeners on the same path or query, the SDK deduplicates them behind the scenes and the data is transferred only once.

You can also just listen to `on('value'` and not handle `child_added` separately, as ReacJS is also quite smart about performing the minimal UI update for the changes. In fact that's what it uses the keys for, and that's why it complains when you have the same key multiple times.

Comment: Thats true. But then I will get each message separate. I want the initial items all at once, and then each new message separate..

Comment: That's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Don't tell me what you want, but why you want that. My guess here is that you want to call `setMessages` only once for the initial set of messages. In that case you can use both `on('value'` and `on('child_added'`, using the latter to handle the data - and the former to detect when it is completed. I added some more on that to my answer.